# Word like "misanthropic", but referring to Nature

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to write a sentence where a person has very negative feelings towards Nature and the natural world. The feelings would be misanthropic, if directed towards people. Is there such a word? I'd like to use it in a sentence such as this one:

> Bob deliberately put his recyclables into the garbage can, being in a particularly [word similar misanthropy but directed at Nature/the natural world] mood, after being pooped on by a pigeon on the way to the office.

Comment: A particularly "fowl" mood perhaps?

Comment: @KitFox: +1 for the pun!

Comment: For that particular example, *[avicidal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avicidal)* works.

Comment: Not an answer as such, but I would probably just recast the entire sentence. “Bob deliberately put his recyclables in the garbage can, **feeling vindictive/spiteful towards Mother Nature** after having been pooped on by a pigeon on the way to the office”, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such word in broad usage occurs to me.  If I wanted that sentence to be easily understood, I would write *nature-hating*, *tree-hating* or *hippie-punching*, depending on what tone I wanted to set.  If I wanted that sentence to provide a satisfying experience for the pretentious classicists in the audience, I would coin *misogaeic*.

Comment: I've used phrases like *tree-hating* in other contexts, but it didn't quite fit how I wanted to use it in the current context. *Misogaeic* could imply what I want although it might be too obscure, but maybe I'll use it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

In the example provided, "environmentally unfriendly" would be an apt play on words.

Comment: It's not a single word. Also, I often hear this phrase being used in the context of ignorance and laziness. The context for the word I want is much more *deliberate* and *spiteful*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he's in an *anti-ecological* mood.

Or an *anticonservationist* mood.

Or a *pro-pollution* mood.

(Also you probably don't need the comma after "mood" and before "after" in your sentence. But I'm having a doubting-myself-on-comma-use week, so someone else should confirm that.)

Comment: I don't really like the hyphenated words, and I'm not 100% sure that *anticonservationist* (maybe it's not a strong enough word).